# How to sort date column in R from latest to earliest and then read the first entry as a vector?

Tags: r, date, vector

For example i have a dataset that looks like this

```
 ID| Date Column| Col3|Col4
 1    2021-02-06    Y    N
 2    2021-03-02    Y    N
 3    2020-01-12    N    N
 4    2021-04-07    Y    Y
 5    2020-03-04    Y    Y
```

My outcome should be

```
x <- ("2021-04-07")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `Date` class and get the `max`

```
x <- max(as.Date(df1[["Date Column"]]))
x
#[1] "2021-04-07"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, `Date Column` = c("2021-02-06", "2021-03-02", 
"2020-01-12", "2021-04-07", "2020-03-04"), Col3 = c("Y", "Y", 
"N", "Y", "Y"), Col4 = c("N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do `max` over character column `Date Column`, i.e.,

```
> with(
+   df,
+   max(`Date Column`)
+ )
[1] "2021-04-07"
```